# Variable looks empty when comparing against string

Tags: javascript

```
 //this is my hmlhttprequest
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
     ajax.open("GET","mydomain/reg-process.php?info="+userVal+"&input=username",true);
     ajax.send();
     ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
       var gotuser = ajax.responseText;
       console.log('results=>'+gotuser);// it alert/console.log 'userok'.
       if(gotuser ==="userok"){  // its like the gotuser is empty,if i compare 'userok' against 'userok' it works."
          do something; // when variable matchs the string.
       }
     }
     }
```

The information gets send to my other page where is processed and return the result. I can read it with console and alert, but when I'm comparing them against the string it doesn't work. I also tested `typeof()` and it also returns type as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this problem arises due to extra white space, Please try the following:

```
if(gotuser.trim() ==="userok"){  
          do something; 
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot man. other question. how to code and make it readable keeping the spaces and comments without make all this trouble?

Comment: gotuser.trim().toLowerCase() === "userok". Just to make it more foolproof.

Comment: @DavidAndrade Please mark the solution as accepted if it worked for you.As it will be of great help to others  too. :-)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @DavidAndrade just click on the tick mark displayed at the left hand side of the answer, below the voting info.

Comment: thanks man, was searching for a option on the post to do that, didnt imagine clicking on that  thing ^^.